Как сделать сферу из кубов в Python Ursina
Помогите с написанием кода для Python на Ursina. Проблемой заключается в создании сферы из кубов. Приведу базовый код:
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        for z in range(3):
            Entity(model='cube', position=(x, y, z))


EditorCamera()
app.run()

Данный код который написан сверху создает куб из 27 других кубов (3x3x3). Каким образом можно сделать сферу из этих кубов?

Ну наверное нужно погуглить формулу сферы. Хотя кубов наверное сильно больше нужно будет, чтобы что-то похожее на сферу получилось.

@CrazyElf Нет, кубов много не надо, сфера задумывается быть с углами кубов и с радиусом 3 куба.

Как вариант просто добавить условие math.sqrt((x - 4) ** 2 + (y - 4) ** 2 + (z - 4) ** 2) <= 3 на создание куба, при этом изменив размеры на 888.

@gord1402 Спасибо большое!

Использовать условие: if math.sqrt((x - 4) ** 2 + (y - 4) ** 2 + (z - 4) ** 2) <= 3:
for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        for z in range(8):
            if math.sqrt((x - 4) ** 2 + (y - 4) ** 2 + (z - 4) ** 2) <= 3:
                Entity(model='cube', position=(x, y, z))

